# Generic Data Access Layer for any DataSource in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have the Vb.net project that is having Msacess Database with DAO objects.

Now i want to migrate from msaccess to mysql with ado.net.

Can any one suggest me to design DAL for any type of Datasource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use an ORM tool (Object-Relational Mapping) like [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/). Most ORM tool can be configured to work with many different database.